# How to merge two meshes together, automatically fill all holes and remove intersecting faces

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am writing a procedural mesh generator for modern low poly planets in python. 
The addon works like that:

At first a mesh is created (cube, uvsphere, icosphere, ...). For continent creation a certain part of the mesh needs to be selected and will be cut out of the mesh (via addon). Now this new object will be manipulated and for example a decimate modifier is applied to that mesh. After the continent is created like the user wants it the two meshes are joined together (STRG + J). Of course now there are holes, sometimes a face intersects with another and the vertex counts of one edge loop isn't the same as the vertex cound of the other edge loop.

I tried to use bridge edge loops, but that only works for some meshes and not all. I also tried to use the boolean modifier with mode union to resolve the intersected faces but the modifier only works great when the mesh doesn't have holes. I even used ShrinkWrap in projection mode to let the meshes 'grow' together. Sadly this didn't work, too.

I need a working solution which automatically resolves intersections (for example cut the face where another face intersects it, remove the cutted part and merge the two edges together) and creates new vertices/edges/faces to connect the meshes. I really don't care if the solution adds a lot of vertices and faces. I would decimate the planet-mesh before it is exported and maybe remove douples with a certain threshold. It just should look good.

I know that it's not really your duty to do that for me, but I need a advice what modifiers I could use for that (and in what order the modifier should be applied). Or maybe I could achieve that with python really fast.

Here is a blend file with a obj called PlaTor Planet and another obj Con 1. Con 1 and Plator Planet should be joined, merged and there mustn't be holes.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38071

Thank you very much for any help or advice!

Comment: Looking at your .blend I can't really make sense of how your meshes got like that or why the cube is ripped open and non-manifold. However, maybe the Intersect Tool (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rwvxusuJXU) could be used in your case to join the meshes instead of using a Boolean Modifier. Then any leftover internal faces could be found using Select Non-Manifold, and deleted. Might that be a solution for you?

Comment: The cube is rippen open because the selected region was seperated. Than the region was a new object with a new mesh. The vertices were manipulated with for example noise (moved along their normal) and to get a modern low poly look a decimate modifier was used. How does the intersect-tool joins meshes?

Comment: I still don't really understand what's happening with your cube mesh. As for the Intersect Tool, you would join the meshes first, then either intersect the selected portion with the non-selected portion or self-intersect. See the video link I posted for details.

Comment: 1. Cube was created 2. Some faces where selected 3. Via Seperate-Tool the selection was cut out. 4. The cut out part was manipulated AND decimated